# Sublime with Emmet: Highlight text in a tabstop inside a custom snippet

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, emmet

When using the Emmet plugin in Sublime Text, if you type a `!` and then hit tab it outputs an HTML5 template. I noticed that inside this template, the `<title>` tag not only has a tabstop, but it also has the title text highlighted to allow for quick replacement.

I'm aware the pipe character (`|`) sets up tabstops for the cursor, but is it possible to highlight a group of characters inside your own custom snippet file?

Answer (score 0):

Ha! Found it.

To highlight text inside a tabstop in your own customized snippet, you need to use the TextMate format for tabstops (i.e. `${1}`).

To do the highlighting, place a colon after the number and just before the text to highlight. So for example, you could do something like this: `${1:This text will be highlighted}`. The next time you expand your customized snippet, the editor will highlight all text inside the tabstop.

If you have multiple tabstops that use this technique, then Sublime will highlight each group of text as you tab over it.